# Allow folder access only to admin user

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm new to ASPX and VB.NET and i'm trying to create two different content for two kinds of users.

Actually all pages for a normal user are ready and now i'm trying to make the Admin part i've created a folder Administrator in which there is a index.aspx that only user that logged and have as role in the database "ADMIN" should access it.

The loggin part is done as the following:

```
Protected Sub loginBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If UserExists(username.Value, password.Value) Then
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username.Value, False)
        If username.Value = "gab" Then
            Page.Response.Redirect("\Administrator\Index.aspx", True)
        Else
            Page.Response.Redirect("Default.aspx", True)
        End If

    Else
        username.Value = ""
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "alert", "openModal();", True)
    End If

End Sub
```

For now i just check if the username is "gab" but lately i'd a function that SELECT the role from the database.

The issue is that if a normal user log and in the path just write \Administrator\index.aspx he can access that folder and even if an administrator change path to "Default.aspx" he can access content of a normal user

I would do that a normal user could see just his aspx pages and the admin just pages in Administrator folder but i need some suggestions on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can do it, including many not listed here. 
You may consider checking the permissions of each user on page load and redirecting them when necessary.  This does add mean that you are hitting the database again on each page load, so you'll need to take that into consideration.
You may also try using client side storage, like a cookie, and running the checks client side.  You'll want to be careful with what you store on the client side as it may open up security vulnerabilities. 
If I knew more about your project, I may be able to give you more specifics.

Comment: Actually it's a website where a normal user can download latest version of software that he bought in our company and he even can create a support tiket where he compile a form and can attach some files for the support all this part is yet ready but now i need an admin part where an admin can create new user, load updates for software and manage the support tickets.

Comment: So do you think that it will not slow down the website if like onLogin i check the permission of the user set in database and like set them in a variable then i'll check it onLoad and if the user logged is not an admin i'd redirect him to login page?

Comment: I think that would work just fine. I'd consider setting something in the cookie, but you'll want to be sure it is encrypted so you don't have any security issues.  That would be faster than constantly hitting the database.